# the_post_thumbnail shows just one post image

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've created 3 posts and I assigned them to "body1-items" category
see comments for img

I want to show them dynamically, each one in her div.

so, In the front-page.php I create a loop

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnwns.png

inside the src of the image I put the_post_thumbnail() function to retrieve the images from the 3 posts but the result is this,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsxmS.jpg

they got just the img of the last post and put it on all the 3 posts. plz help me ?

note, when I set the posts_per_page to 3 or more, I got the 3 divs three times!! see comments for img

this is the hole code : pastebin.com/EBHME6dS

Comment: You don't have three posts in your loop. You've set `posts_per_page` to 1. You're outputting the same post thumbnail 3 times in a single iteration of your while loop

Comment: thanks but I have 3 posts: http://imgur.com/a/HFfXL

Comment: when I set the posts_per_page to 3 or more, I got the 3 divs three times!!
http://imgur.com/a/tO9BT

Comment: Yes, you are printing the same image of each post 3 times in your loop. That's why it's showing same image 3 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code,

```
<?php
  $images = array();
  while( $myquery->have_posts() ) : 
     $myquery->the_post();
     $images[] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
  endwhile; 
?>
```

Set posts_per_page to 3. 
Now your images are in the array. Use $images[0], $images[1] & $images[2] in your Div elements.
Print your html below the loop.

**Update**: Its very straight forward. Just add the below code just below the your loop,

```
<div class="body1">
   <div class="container bb">
   <?php 
      $myquery = new WP_Query('category_name=body1-items&posts_per_page=3');
     $images = array();
     while( $myquery->have_posts() ) : 
         $myquery->the_post();
         $images[] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
    endwhile; 
   ?>
   <div class="a870">
    <img class="bor-img" src="<?php echo $images[0]; ?>">
</div>
<div class="sup">
    <img class="bor-img" src="<?php echo $images[1]; ?>">
    <img class="bor-img smaly" src="<?php echo $images[2]; ?>">
    </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
   </div>
```

Comment: this is the hole code : https://pastebin.com/EBHME6dS
can you plz add the fix code that you gave me to it cause I have some problem figuring out where to place the code.
thannks bro

Comment: I really appreciate you help but when I run the code : http://imgur.com/a/bhzgd
I got the same result like this: http://imgur.com/a/sFhkS
the debugger throw some errors att me : http://imgur.com/a/uiqEl
thanks

Comment: I tested the code myself & it works fine. Just use the 2 code block's next to each other. Close while/endwhile  before the HTML block.

Comment: can you plz screen shot the code that worked for you ?

Comment: Updated the code to your needs. Just copy/paste the 2nd code block. But this is against the rules of SO. Please learn coding or hire a developer next time.

Comment: maaan thank you so much, if you want just delete it I got it.

Comment: how can I set the number between [] to be dynamic? cause each time I add photo in the same gategory I have to set it to 0 or the related number ?